# Regular expression to capture Jan 1987 as well as 1987

Tags: regex

```
Exercise 12: Matching Nested Groups
Task    Text    Capture Groups   
Capture Jan 1987    Jan 1987 1987   Failed
Capture May 1969    May 1969 1969   Failed
Capture Aug 2011    Aug 2011 2011   Failed
```

I found the solution `((...)\s\d{1,4})|(\d{1,4})` but it's not accepting

Comment: Please give a reason for downvoting

Comment: These questions make no sense - read the regexone explanations, try your patterns at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), *search the Web* for more details (best sites are regular-expressions.info and rexegg.com, but there are much more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
([A-Za-z]+\s)?\d{1,4}
```

That will select an optional word before the number

However, after viewing the exercise on RegexOne, to capture what you need to complete the task, use:

```
((?:[A-Za-z]+\s)?(\d{1,4}))
```

---

What you did wrong.

```
((...)\s\d{1,4})|(\d{1,4})
```

You needed to capture the Year as well as the Month Name, so **you should have used** the following:

```
(...\s(\d{1,4}))|(\d{1,4})
```

Add `()` around `\d{1,4}` to capture it (and you can remove the `()` around the `...`, since the Month Name, e.g. `Jan` does not need to be captured). You RegEx was capturing either:

- `Jan 1999` and `Jan`
- OR
- `1999`

Now it will capture:

- `Jan 1999` and `1999`
- OR
- `1999`

Comment: I think there is a white space between that word and number ..!

Comment: Its no accepting The scenario is it only accepts 19XX but not Jan 1987

Comment: Yes there is white space.That is why in my solution I used \s

Comment: And care to explain it

Comment: And yes its the answer I will accept it and upvote it just tell me what I was doing wrong and explain what you did

Comment: @SachinDivakar Done. See updated answer. You were not capturing the year when month existed

Comment: Yes exactly that Bro what was confusing me was in website where I was doing exercise.It showed in green which meant the first part before I accepted the JAN 1900 part .But  with this what does that () add to existing pattern.Accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 2):

Original post

```
\b((\w{3})?\s\d{4})\b
```

Regex to match the RegexOne pattern

```
((\w{3})?[\s\b](\d{4}))
```

Forgot a group.

Matches `Mon YEAR` or `YEAR`.

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem dear.Thanks for helping though.It only accepted first part

Comment: ++ for limiting month's name to just 3 characters. But seriously why did you use `\b` in your pattern?

Comment: @SachinDivakar the edited regex works, the initial lacked groups, please see http://i.imgur.com/bme6kE2.png

Comment: @Shafizadeh I'm used to word boundaries instead of spaces, and was not aware of the exercise type.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution for [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/lesson/nested_groups) would be:

```
((Jan|May|Aug)\s(1987|1969|2011))
```

You need to read the text properly, the task was to capture both the *years* as well as the *whole date*.
As @Druzion pointed out, the regex can still be optimized, like so:

```
((?:Jan|May|Aug)\s(\d{4}))
```

This captures the whole date, uses a non capturing group for the month part and captures the year separately.

Comment: These three month `Jan`, `May`, `Agu` are just as an example. I think there is the name of other months too.

Comment: @Druzion: True but the exercise was about parentheses.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: No, the examples are taken directly from the website.

Comment: I want a proper working solution for regex one and I need to know what I did wrong

Comment: @SachinDivakar: I offered two of them :)

Comment: LOL +10 for your sense of humour :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use this expression:
`(\w+\s(\d+))|(\d+)`
this will work fine.